# Update Column using pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table T1 which 3 columns with 100 records. All columns and rows were filled but the first column named ID values are empty. So, I wanted to fill the ID column with numbering order(1,2..100) for 100 rows by using PL/SQL Program. I have tried with rownum and with a sequence which is working fine. I want to try with pl/SQL block. I have also tried to write pl/SQL block, however, not getting the desired result.

```
declare
count1 number;
begin
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO COUNT1 FROM T1;
FOR I IN 1..COUNT1
loop
UPDATE T1 SET ID =I;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: You said your current code did not give the desired result, but you failed to say what result you _did_ get.   However, I can guess that all of the rows got the same id value.  The reason for that is because your UPDATE, inside the loop, does not qualify which row to update.  Therefor, it updates all rows. So, on each pass of the loop, _ALL_ of the rows are updated with the current value of the variable 'I'.

Answer (score 2):

SQL should be the way to do it; but OK, if you're learning PL/SQL, then this might be one option:

Sample table (`ID` column should be populated):

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (name) select ename from emp;

14 rows created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
           SMITH
           ALLEN
           WARD
           JONES
           MARTIN
           BLAKE
           CLARK
           SCOTT
           KING
           TURNER
           ADAMS
           JAMES
           FORD
           MILLER

14 rows selected.
```

Anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> declare
  2    i number := 1;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select rowid rid from test) loop
  5      update test set id = i where rowid = cur_r.rid;
  6      i := i + 1;
  7    end loop;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 SMITH
         2 ALLEN
         3 WARD
         4 JONES
         5 MARTIN
         6 BLAKE
         7 CLARK
         8 SCOTT
         9 KING
        10 TURNER
        11 ADAMS
        12 JAMES
        13 FORD
        14 MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Loops are slow, they process the table row-by-row. Yet another option (you didn't mention and - perhaps - didn't try - is `merge`.

```
SQL> update test set id = null;

14 rows updated.

SQL> begin
  2    merge into test a
  3      using (select b.rowid,
  4                    row_number() over (order by null) rn
  5             from test b
  6            ) x
  7      on (a.rowid = x.rowid)
  8      when matched then update set
  9        a.id = x.rn;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------
         1 SMITH
         2 ALLEN
         3 WARD
         4 JONES
         5 MARTIN
         6 BLAKE
         7 CLARK
         8 SCOTT
         9 KING
        10 TURNER
        11 ADAMS
        12 JAMES
        13 FORD
        14 MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: @littlefoot.....Thank you